Error: Couldnt find the Android build tools @ /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3 when app is running with 33.0.0 in actions github
I was devoloping a script to autobuild the .apk file of my app. However, I'm getting the following error, related with buildToolVersion:
Run r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
  with:
    releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/apk/release
  env:
    JAVA_HOME: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Corretto_jdk/17.0.11-9.1/x64
    JAVA_HOME_17_X64: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Java_Corretto_jdk/17.0.11-9.1/x64
    BUILD_TOOL_VERSION: 34.0.0
Preparing to sign key @ app/build/outputs/apk/release with signing key
Found 1 release files.
Error: Couldnt find the Android build tools @ /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3
Error: Unable to locate executable file: /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/zipalign. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.


My script in github actions is the following:
name: Create release

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
      - name: Set Up JDK
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'corretto'
          server-id: github # Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
          settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }} # location for the settings.xml file

      - name: Change wrapper permissions
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew

      - name: Build Project
        run: ./gradlew build -x test

      - name: Build Release APK
        run: ./gradlew bundleRelease

      - name: Setup build tool version variable
        shell: bash
        run: |
          BUILD_TOOL_VERSION=$(ls /usr/local/lib/android/sdk/build-tools/ | tail -n 1)
          echo "BUILD_TOOL_VERSION=$BUILD_TOOL_VERSION" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo Last build tool version is: $BUILD_TOOL_VERSION
      - name: Sign APK
        uses: r0adkll/sign-android-release@v1
        with:
          releaseDirectory: app/build/outputs/apk/release
          signingKeyBase64: ${{ secrets.SIGN_KEY_STORE_FILE_B64 }}
          alias: ${{ secrets.SIGN_KEY_ALIAS }}
          keyStorePassword: ${{ secrets.SIGN_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD }}
          keyPassword: ${{ secrets.SIGN_KEY_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Get version time  
        uses: 1466587594/get-current-time@v2    
        id: version-name    
        with:   
          format: "YYYY.MMDD.HHmm"

      - name: Rename release APK
        run: mv app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned-signed.apk app/build/outputs/apk/release/cepsa-standalone-app.apk

      - name: Upload Release Build to Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
           name: release-artifacts
           if-no-files-found: error
           path: |
             app/build/outputs/apk/release/cepsa-standalone-app.apk
          
      - name: Create Github Release
        uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
        with:
           tag_name: "v_${{ steps.version-name.outputs.formattedTime }}"
           name: "Cepsa App ${{ steps.version-name.outputs.formattedTime }}"
           draft: true
           prerelease: false
           generate_release_notes: true
           files: |
             app/build/outputs/apk/release/cepsa-standalone-app.apk

And my build.gradle(app) file is this:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization'
}

android {
    namespace 'es.paytef.cepsastandalone'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        buildToolsVersion "33.0.0"
        applicationId "es.paytef.cepsastandalone"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 10
        versionName "10.0"
        buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", base_url)
        buildConfigField("String", "DB_NAME", db_name)
        buildConfigField("String", "DB_SESSION_NAME", db_session_name)
        buildConfigField("String", "DB_SHIFT_NAME", db_shift_name)
        buildConfigField("String", "DB_PRODUCTS_NAME", db_products_name)
        buildConfigField("String", "DB_SELLS_NAME", db_sells_name)

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        // Adds exported schema location as test app assets.
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    kotlin {
        jvmToolchain(17)
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig = true
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.4'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$core_ktx_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:$kotlin_serialization"
    implementation project(path: ':commons')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'

    //ApiConnectionClient
    implementation project(path: ':paytef_sdk')

    //Navigation compose
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.6.0"

    // retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jaxb:$retrofit_version"

    //Singleton and Inject annotation
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.5'
    implementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"

    //hilt libraries for custom Component.
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44"

    //Room libraries
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt)
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
}

And my build.gradle(project):
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        // SDK versions
        sdkMinVersion = 24
        sdkCompileVersion = 33
        sdkTargetVersion = 33
    }
    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.10"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.44"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-serialization:1.8.10"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


Is quite strange due to the script is trying to find a buildToolVersion, which is not configured in the app.
If you have some  experience in issue like this, take thanks in advance !

I think you just made a typo, BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION with S  not BUILD_TOOL_VERSION
